# db4o Transparent Activation - Null Exception on retrieving children values of a node

Tags: java, db4o, activation

I create a tree of nodes, and I store it in Database for Object Oriented (db4o). Because I want an efficient loading of the nodes from the database, I use Transparent Activation, and I implement the Activatable interface. My Node class is the following:

```
package directory_service_server;

import com.db4o.activation.ActivationPurpose;
import com.db4o.activation.Activator;
import com.db4o.ta.Activatable;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Node implements Activatable{

    private String name;
    private String attribute;
    private ArrayList<Node> children;
    private transient Activator _activator; 
    //Node father;

    public Node()
    {
        this.name="";
        this.attribute="";
        this.children= new ArrayList<Node>();
      //  this.father= new Node ();
    }
    public Node(String name, String attribute, ArrayList<Node> children)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.attribute=attribute;
        this.children=children;

    }

    void setName(String name)
    {

        this.name=name;
    }

    void setAttribute(String attribute)
    {
        this.attribute=attribute;
    }

    void setChildren(ArrayList<Node> children)
    {
       this.children=children; 

    }


    String getName()
    {
        this.activate(ActivationPurpose.READ);
        return name;
    }

    String getAttribute()
    {
        this.activate(ActivationPurpose.READ);
        return this.attribute;
    }

    String getAttributeWithoutActivation()
    {
        return this.attribute;
    }

    ArrayList<Node> getChildren()
    {
        this.activate(ActivationPurpose.READ);
        return children;
    }


    @Override
    public void activate(ActivationPurpose purpose) {
        if(_activator!=null)
            _activator.activate(purpose);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Activator activator) {

        if(_activator==activator)
        {
            return;
        }


        if(activator!=null && _activator!=null )
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

         _activator=activator;   
    }




}
```

When I load the root (some node) from the database, and I start to traverse the graph, My traversing method, (which also prints the node values) is the following:

```
 void displayTree(Node node)
    {
        System.out.print(node.getName()+"-");
        for(int i=0; i<node.getChildren().size(); i++)
            displayTree(node.getChildren().get(i));
    }
```

What is confusing me is that for "some traversals", I can't decide which ones, I get a Null Exception when I do the traversal. I get the exception on the following line in the method above:

```
for(int i=0; i<node.getChildren().size(); i++)
```

My interpretation is that the children of the node is NULL and so accessing the size() method gives me NULL. I think maybe I am missing something in my implementation for the Activatable class. I used the follwing source for my implementation, but I did not find other sources. http://docs.huihoo.com/db4o/db4o-7.0-java-tutorial.pdf

Can someone help me by telling me what I am missing? Below is part of the stack trace,

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at directory_service_server.Tree.displayTree(Tree.java:88)
    at directory_service_server.Tree.displayTree(Tree.java:89)
    at directory_service_server.Tree.displayTree(Tree.java:89)
    at directory_service_server.Tree.displayTree(Tree.java:89)
    at directory_service_server.ClientHandler.registerService(ClientHandler.java:187)
    at directory_service_server.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
com.db4o.events.EventException
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.withExceptionHandlingInCallback(EventRegistryImpl.java:283)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.triggerObjectInfoEventInCallback(EventRegistryImpl.java:270)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.objectOnNew(EventRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.objectOnNew(ObjectReference.java:194)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.continueSet(ObjectReference.java:180)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.stillToSet(ObjectContainerBase.java:1902)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.store2(ObjectContainerBase.java:1698)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.storeAfterReplication(ObjectContainerBase.java:1618)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$10.apply(ObjectContainerBase.java:1604)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$10.apply(ObjectContainerBase.java:1602)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.asTopLevelCall(ObjectContainerBase.java:427)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.asTopLevelStore(ObjectContainerBase.java:413)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.storeInternal(ObjectContainerBase.java:1602)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.MarshallingContext.writeObject(MarshallingContext.java:252)
    at com.db4o.internal.OpenTypeHandler.writeObject(OpenTypeHandler.java:266)
    at com.db4o.internal.OpenTypeHandler.write(OpenTypeHandler.java:251)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.MarshallingContext.writeObjectWithCurrentState(MarshallingContext.java:272)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.MarshallingContext.writeObject(MarshallingContext.java:260)
    at com.db4o.typehandlers.CollectionTypeHandler.writeElements(CollectionTypeHandler.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use [Activatable collections](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/collections/ActivatableCollection.html) instead of normal Collection(s) ? There is activatable collection for every standards java collection. Thoses collection have ActivationPurpose.READ/WRITE  already defined.

I also think that you are using "Transparent Activation" but not the "annotations" so you need to define ActivationPurpose for each of your setter / getter.
in my project I do exactly as 
[versant db4o transparent activation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/tutorial/docs/TransparentActivation.html) and its working fine.

You should also look at *transparentpersistence* + *ta_enhanced_example* to get the right annotation process its a little magic but it work at the end.